# How can I combine dates in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column SCHEDULE_DATE and two columns: RESET_HOUR and RESET_MINUTE. I need to combine them and create a new column with dateteime format. For example:

| SCHEDULE_DATE | RESET_HOUR | RESET_MINUTE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 28.01.2021 | 1 | 30 |
| 12.02.2021 | 0 | 15 |

I need like this:

| SCHEDULE_DATE | RESET_HOUR | RESET_MINUTE | SCHEDULE_DATETIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28.01.2021 | 1 | 30 | 28.01.2021 01:30 |
| 12.02.2021 | 0 | 15 | 12.02.2021 00:15 |

thank you!

Comment: Oracle does not have a `DATETIME` data type. It has `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` and both of them **ALWAYS** have a time component (`TIMESTAMP` optionally also has fractional seconds and time zone components).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `SCHEDULE_DATETIME` already exist, you may use the following update:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET SCHEDULE_DATETIME = CAST(SCHEDULE_DATE AS timestamp) +
                            RESET_HOUR / 24.0 + RESET_MINUTE / 60 / 24;
```

If you instead just want to *view* this computed column, then use the same logic in a select:

```sql
SELECT *, CAST(SCHEDULE_DATE AS timestamp) +
          RESET_HOUR / 24.0 + RESET_MINUTE / 60 / 24 AS SCHEDULE_DATETIME
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without updating a table? Just in a SELECT clause

Comment: @СаятОразов Yes, please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to change the data type from `DATE` and can use:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       TRUNC(schedule_date)
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL( reset_hour, 'HOUR')
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL( reset_minute, 'MINUTE') AS schedule_datetime
FROM   table_name t;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       TRUNC(schedule_date)
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL( reset_hour * 60 + reset_minute, 'MINUTE')
         AS schedule_datetime
FROM   table_name t;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       TRUNC(schedule_date)
       + (reset_hour * 60 + reset_minute) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
         AS schedule_datetime
FROM   table_name t;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       TRUNC(schedule_date) + reset_hour/24 + reset_minute/24/60
         AS schedule_datetime
FROM   table_name t;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (SCHEDULE_DATE, RESET_HOUR, RESET_MINUTE) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-01-28', 1, 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-02-12', 0, 15 FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

> | SCHEDULE_DATE | RESET_HOUR | RESET_MINUTE | SCHEDULE_DATETIME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021-01-28 00:00:00 | 1 | 30 | 2021-01-28 01:30:00 |
> | 2021-02-12 00:00:00 | 0 | 15 | 2021-02-12 00:15:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=73a811db8e95328c4fac62470475d7f9)*